# Determine if instance has Multi-Currency Enabled

Tags: api, c#, standard-objects, multi-currency

Is there a way to check if an instance has Multi-Currency enabled through the API?
I know that when enabling Multi-Currency, a CurrencyType object and multiple other fields are added on to each object.

Is there any other way other than querying for the CurrencyType object / CurrencyIsoCode on objects and then handling the INVALID_TYPE exception thrown when those fields are not in an instance without Multi-Currency enabled?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to sfdcfox for his [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96380/22601) in APEX.  I was able to convert this into C# and here's what I got:

```
var currencyType = sForce.describeGlobal().sobjects.Where(x => x.name == "CurrencyType").FirstOrDefault();
```

It returs null if the org doesnt have multicurrency enabled and an initialized CurrencyType sObject if the org does.

Comment: I missed the C# flag, but yes, this is quite a bit easier than trying to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

```
Boolean multiCurrencyEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('CurrencyType');
```

If this check is true, it's safe to use CurrencyIsoCode fields and the CurrencyType object. I'd recommend using a static variable so it can be initialized just once per transaction.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible way is via [UserInfo Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm).

`Boolean multiCurrencyEnabled = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization();`